# Compass Flexbox

Tags: flexbox, compass

I'm trying to test this flexbox layout model in compass.
I run into problem, when I copy entire example to my localhost: http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/flexbox/

I get following error:

```
error: assets/sass/main.scss (Line 94 of /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_flexbox.scss: Mixin flexbox takes 0 arguments but 1 was passed.)
```

To compile my scss files I use grunt-contrib-compass

ruby: 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]

compass: Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)

Sass 3.4.3 (Selective Steve)

grunt-contrib-compass: "~0.9.1"

Same error I get when I run 'Compass watch'.
Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a but, I had duplicate mixin :P